# What does 迷路の奥のダイヤ mean?

Tags: words, song-lyrics, metaphor

Found it in the lyrics of [BUMP OF CHICKEN - Answer](https://lyricsjpop.blogspot.com.au/2016/12/bump-of-chicken-answer.html)

> 想像つかない昨日を越えて　その延長の明日を抱えて
>   小さな肩　震える今　それでも笑った
>   **迷路の奥のダイヤ**のような
>   届かなかった風船のような
>   気づけなかった流星のような
>   涙をもらった

I googled a lot without a clue finally. Is it a reference of a game or something?

Comment: Do you understand ダイヤのような modifies 涙 three lines after it?

Comment: @naruto I understand but it's not related. The major question here is what a ダイヤ of 「迷路の奥」 is. It's kinda I know what 迷路 is, what 奥 is, what ダイヤ is, but I didn't get the combination.

Comment: @naruto The question is not related to grammar. I thought 「迷路の奥のダイヤ」 came from a reference somehow but it turned out it was simply an analogy: https://youtu.be/bRWQckbQ9tQ?t=3m1s

Comment: Oh, so you intentionally dropped the last half of the sentence in question, while including the unrelated previous sentence :) Anyway, I also think this 迷路の奥のダイヤ is not a reference to any well-known phenomenon.

Comment: @naruto No, I did not intentionally did that. The lyrics website blocked text selection and I was only able to copy the lyrics via developer tools. It was troublesome and since they were not quite related, I just copied several lines before it. And the question did not get tagged with [`words`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/words/info) for no reason: "Any question that does **not** deal specifically with grammar..." Don't be like, "The question is a bit off. He must have meant something else and failed to explain it." It's Japanese StackExchange not Detective StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Having read the entire lyrics, I would say that that part is saying:

"Your tears are as precious as a diamond (hidden) in the inner part of a labyrinth".

(As a non-game-player, I could not answer the game reference bit.  I can, however, say that at least there is no such suggestion made in the lyrics.)

Comment: Actually after wasting plenty of my time googling the meaning of it, I watched the MV and it seems to have an answer: https://youtu.be/bRWQckbQ9tQ?t=3m1s